# What Kind Of Mathematics Is Comparing Numbers?

Tags: number-comparison

We can compare 2 numbers with >, <, >=, <=, or = . And get a "true" or "false" result.

I believe this is some kind of mathematics. What kind is it?

Comment: These are examples of [binary relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation), and more general types of relations also exist.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I'm not sure what the official name, if any, is for comparing numbers, but it's sometimes called comparative math (since you're comparing values), e.g., there are a few examples at [Comparison Math Problems](https://www.testprepreview.com/modules/comparisonmath.htm), and there's also an article [Comparative Mathematical Language in the Elementary School: A Longitudinal Study](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10649-006-4627-5). Finally, there's a YouTube [Comparative math](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTPYaZvVb7C7olP7Y7pITlxnfxT273Z9i) page.